# In NPM workspaces Typescript fails to compile. In the rest of monorepository Typescript compiles correctly

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, eslint, monorepo

We have refactored our project to be a mono repository (NPM Workspaces) and structure it like so:

```
 |-- apps          
   |-- native         <-- Not Workspace
   |-- web            <-- Not Workspace
 |-- common        
   |-- models         <-- Workspace
   |-- connectors     <-- Workspace
   |-- store          <-- Workspace
   |-- types          <-- Workspace
   |-- utils          <-- Workspace
 -- package-lock.json
 -- package.json
```

Our `native` and `web` apps use code from `common` and do not share code between them.

```
root package.json
-----------------
{
  "name": "@secret/client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "workspaces": [
    "./common/*"
  ]
}
```

## The problem

When compiling Typescript files, **only** the Typescript files in the `common` folder fail to compile and throw `Parsing error: Unexpected token` errors. The rest of Typescript files in `native` and `web` compile correctly.
[image]

Webpack module.rules

```
[
  { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
  {
    oneOf: [
      ...irrelevantRulesIntentionallyHidden,
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        include: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp',
        loader: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js',
        options: {
          customize: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\webpack-overrides.js',
          presets: [
            [
              'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\index.js',
              [Object]
            ]
          ],
          babelrc: false,
          configFile: false,
          cacheIdentifier: 'development:babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.3.7:babel-preset-react-app@10.0.0:react-dev-utils@11.0.4:react-scripts@4.0.3',
          plugins: [
            [
              'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\babel-plugin-named-asset-import\\index.js',
              [Object]
            ],
            'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\react-refresh\\babel.js'
          ],
          cacheDirectory: true,
          cacheCompression: false,
          compact: false,
          sourceType: 'unambiguous'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
        exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
        loader: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js',
        options: {
          babelrc: false,
          configFile: false,
          compact: false,
          presets: [
            [
              'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\dependencies.js',
              [Object]
            ]
          ],
          cacheDirectory: true,
          cacheCompression: false,
          cacheIdentifier: 'development:babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.3.7:babel-preset-react-app@10.0.0:react-dev-utils@11.0.4:react-scripts@4.0.3',
          sourceMaps: true,
          inputSourceMap: true,
          sourceType: 'unambiguous'
        },
        include: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp'
      },
    ] 
  }
]
```

ESLintWebpackPlugin

```
{
  key: 'ESLintWebpackPlugin',
  options: {
    extensions: [ 'js', 'mjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx' ],
    emitError: true,
    emitWarning: true,
    failOnError: true,
    formatter: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\node_modules\\react-dev-utils\\eslintFormatter.js',
    eslintPath: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\eslint\\lib\\api.js',
    context: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp',
    cache: true,
    cacheLocation: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\.cache\\.eslintcache',
    cwd: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web',
    resolvePluginsRelativeTo: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config',
    baseConfig: {
      extends: [
        'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\eslint-config-react-app\\base.js'
      ],
      rules: {}
    },
    overrideConfig: {
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [ 0 ],
        'no-use-before-define': [ 0 ],
        'no-useless-escape': [ 0 ],
        'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': [ 0 ],
        'unicode-bom': [ 0 ],
        'react/button-has-type': [ 2, [Object] ],
        'react/jsx-no-literals': [ 2, [Object] ]
      },
      plugins: [ 'react' ]
    },
    ignore: true
  },
  run: [Function: bound run] AsyncFunction
}
```

ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin

```
{
    eslint: false,
    eslintOptions: {},
    tsconfigPath: undefined,
    compiler: undefined,
    started: undefined,
    elapsed: undefined,
    cancellationToken: undefined,
    isWatching: false,
    checkDone: false,
    compilationDone: false,
    diagnostics: [],
    lints: [],
    eslintVersion: undefined,
    startAt: 0,
    nodeArgs: [],
    options: {
      typescript: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib\\typescript.js',
      async: true,
      checkSyntacticErrors: true,
      resolveModuleNameModule: undefined,
      resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveModule: undefined,
      tsconfig: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\tsconfig.json',
      reportFiles: [Array],
      silent: true,
      formatter: undefined
    },
    ignoreDiagnostics: [],
    ignoreLints: [],
    ignoreLintWarnings: false,
    reportFiles: [
      '../**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
      '**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
      '!**/src/**/__tests__/**',
      '!**/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
      '!**/src/setupProxy.*',
      '!**/src/setupTests.*'
    ],
    logger: Object [console] {...}, <--- too long to paste
    typescriptPath: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib\\typescript.js',
    typescriptVersion: '4.2.3',
    tsconfig: 'C:\\_git\\Secret\\src\\Secret.WebClient\\ClientApp\\apps\\web\\tsconfig.json',
    compilerOptions: {},
    vue: { compiler: 'vue-template-compiler', enabled: false },
    useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true,
    measureTime: false
  }
```

Example: common/connectors/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@secret/connectors",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "tslint-react": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

## Does anyone have experience with this? What do you think could be the solution?

Comment: Check out the Webpack section on this article and let me know if it helps. We ran into something similar and we had to tell Webpack and TypeScript to resolve the source files instead of using the symlinks from npm workspaces while building.

https://medium.com/@NiGhTTraX/making-typescript-monorepos-play-nice-with-other-tools-a8d197fdc680

Comment: @evelynhathaway thank you for the link. I have tried implementing suggested `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` and few other solutions under create-react-app section with no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue solved

There is a bug in **ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin** create-react-app (CRA) uses. Updating it to the latest version (at the time of writing `6.2.10`) and using this CRA override solves the issue:

```
// Use newer version of ForkTSCheckerWebpackPlugin to type check
// files across the monorepo.
const forkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = config.plugins.findIndex(
  (p) => p.reportFiles
);
if (forkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin !== -1) {
  config.plugins.splice(
    forkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin,
    1,
    new ForkTSCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      issue: {
        // The exclude rules are copied from CRA.
        exclude: [
          {
            file: "**/src/**/__tests__/**",
          },
          {
            file: "**/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).*",
          },
          {
            file: "**/src/setupProxy.*",
          },
          {
            file: "**/src/setupTests.*",
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  );
}
```

Solution courtesy: @NiGhTTraX
https://github.com/NiGhTTraX/ts-monorepo/issues/74